# Use Android App Icons for Sharing

Tags: android, legal

I got a question about licensing of android app icons.

At the moment I am developing an app and I implemented a share function.

The user can select a prefered app to share a text message in a popup dialog. Like Whatsapp or Email or whatever app he would like to send the message...

The set of apps he can choose from is built dynamically and based on a list you can get from the android system for a "shareintent".
That means that if you have other apps installed that accept this kind of intent it will list them all.

This is a kind of "application chooser" so you get the app name and its icon displayed.

This preference is saved and you can always see what you chose by looking at the icon of the saved app-preference at the bottom of the screen.
It is pretty similar to the android intern "shareactionprovider" which has this displaying of app icons in common (like seen in the standard galery app).

The question is now if I do break some copyright or licencing laws by displaying this icons, but keep in mind that android has the key features as well which do not fit in my app.

If I want to use the icons, do I have to ask all companies for allowance? This would be insane because like I said it is dynamically...

I found some other licensing information but nothing does fit this special case of mine.. like this one:

[Is it legal to use icons from some other application while developing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150144/is-it-legal-to-use-icons-from-some-other-application-while-developing)

I hope you guys understand what I am trying to ask you. I can also put some screenshots in. Please excuse my English, because it is not my first language.

Greets